# perl regex to grep for a character in a word

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to write a perl script to grep for a character in a string. All the strings are stored in an array. We iterate over the array and look if the particular word occurs, if so grep for a particular pattern.

```
my @array = ("Foo1", "Bar", "Baz", "Foo5", "Foo2", "Bak", "Foo3");
foreach my $ var (@array){
    if ($var =~ /Foo/){
        #Regex to grep for the number which is at the end of string Foo
    }
}
```

Any leads are welcomed. Thanks for the help.

************Edits***********

Thanks for the comments.

```
if ($var =~ /Foo/){
    /.Foo+([A-Z]+)/;
    print $1, "\n";
}
```

The above is the code that I tried and it didn't print anything.

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: We generally don't write code for you from scratch. Explain what you've tried and where you are having trouble.

Comment: Oh you want us to fill in your comment... Give it a go yourself, and post what you did and how it didn't work, then you'll get help.

Comment: @Jim W
I didn't expect that it would be a problem if I would ask to suggest an idea for the regex and the edit I made now was already attempted initially and I didn't expect anyone to write code for me from scratch.
Thanks for your comment, in future will keep in mind to post my failed attempts.

Comment: @Jim Garrison
I didn't expect that it would be a problem if I would ask to suggest an idea for the regex and the edit I made now was already attempted initially and I didn't expect anyone to write code for me from scratch. Thanks for your comment, in future will keep in mind to post my failed attempts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matching without binding `=~` matches against the $_ variable that you don't use. Furthermore, the dot before `Foo` means the second regex will match only if Foo is preceded by something (that's not a newline). As all your strings containing `Foo` start with it, the second regex can never match even if you specify `$var =~`.

Moreover, you can match the number directly in the condition.

And finally, `[A-Z]` doesn't match digits. Use `[0-9]` instead.

```
my @array = qw( Foo1 Bar Baz Foo5 Foo2 Bak Foo3 );
foreach my $var (@array){
    if ($var =~ /Foo([0-9]+)/){
        print $1, "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will this regex work? 
`/Foo+([A-Za-z_0-9]+)/;` and then use `print $1` to print that character.

Comment: Why the plus after Foo? Do your data contain `Foooo`, too?

Comment: I mis-understood + in my regex. Got it now.
Your regex fixes my issue. Thanks for the help. 
One more blocking thing, could you explain the `+` in your regex.

Comment: @V.Tej: `[0-9]` matches one digit, `[0-9]+` matches one or more digits.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for your second regex

```
[^\w]*([0-9])
```

Then you can use the first group to get the number.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
my @array = qw( Foo1 Bar Baz Foo5 Foo2 Bak Foo3 );
my @var = map(/Foo(\w+)/) @array;

print @var ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.